# Nodemon crashes and shows waiting for file changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I am using nodemon version 1.18.3 and express version 4. 
Upon running nodemon command directly, I get the following error:

```html
events.js:165
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1346:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1387:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1475:7)
    at Function.app.listen (/home/rishabh/Documents/my_projects/getting_MEAN/loc8r/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:531:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rishabh/Documents/my_projects/getting_MEAN/loc8r/bin/www:7:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1366:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:697:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Nodemon crashes and keeps on waiting for file changes.

Comment: try this out`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524298 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`. let me know if it fixes, then I can make an answer.

Comment: nodemon uses something called `inotify watchers`, which allows `nodemon` to watch your file system. Unfortunately, when this limit exceeds nodemon is not able to watch changes in your code. This is mentioned here: https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Comment: It's happed because your file have some error or your code having some error. Nodemon  telling to you correct all the error you have in your application. After all error gone nodemon automatically start the server.

Comment: @PrashantGupta if that was the case, then it shouldn't have given the listen error at port 3000.

Comment: @RishabhGupta please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because nodemon can't watch your file system as mentioned in this [issue on github](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/702).

Basically, there's something known as `inotify` watchers which nodemon uses to watch the changes that you do in your code.

You can fix this by increasing the amount of max watchers and then restart your computer to apply the changes:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524298 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

It's also mentioned [here](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers).

or you can also add the following code in your endpoint file:

```
process.on('SIGUSR2', () => { process.exit(0); });
```

Comment: @RishabhGupta oh, it was my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

The error says that the port `3000` is already in use.

You need to use another port, you can use the below command,

```
nodemon ./YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.js localhost 3005
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/702. which means your solution is a temporary fix.

Comment: It might be the port. I received this error after running an app with nodemon in VScode's terminal. At one point I tried to exit it, and it didn't work. I later tried doing it from the regular terminal and it gave me this error. Had to shutdown VScode and restart it.

Comment: @DakshMiglani Just gone through the post, Very informative. but generally `EADDRINUSE` errors occur due to non availability of ports.

Comment: @DavidR true, but usually port 3000 is used for a dev-server, which means he was running this server and changed some code but then this issue happened and the fix for this is to increase watchers.